# Debug Assertion Failed with rgbConverted.cpp

Tags: c++-cli

First saying, It's a duplicate question, but not the same problem.
When I run my code, this message is showing, but no error.

[image: Error]

```
#pragma once
using namespace System::Drawing;

ref class rgbConvert
{
private: 
    System::Drawing::Bitmap^ grayImage;
    System::Drawing::Bitmap^ bainaryImage;
    System::Drawing::Bitmap^ rgbImage;
    int xsize;
    int ysize;
    bool **BArray;
    int **GrayArray;
    int **binary;
    FILE *fp;

static float coef01 = (float)0.2989;
static float coef02 = (float)0.5870;
static float coef03 = (float)0.1140;

public:

rgbConvert(System::Drawing::Bitmap^ im)
{
    rgbImage = im;
    xsize = rgbImage->Height;
    ysize = rgbImage->Width;
}

rgbConvert(int height, int width)
{
    xsize = height;
    ysize = width;
}

int** getGrayImageArray ()
{
    GrayArray = new int * [xsize];
    for (int i = 0; i < xsize; i++ )
    {
        GrayArray[i] = new int[ysize];
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < this->xsize; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < this->ysize; j++ )
        {
            System::Drawing::Color^ clr = this->rgbImage->GetPixel(j, i);
            int pixel = clr->ToArgb();              

            //int alpha = (pixel >> 24) & 0xff;// no need here
            int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
            int green = (pixel >>  8) & 0xff;
            int blue = (pixel      ) & 0xff;

            int grayC = int(coef01*red + coef02*green + coef03*blue);

            GrayArray[i][j] = grayC;
        }// inner for*/
    }

    return GrayArray;
}

void getGrayImageArray (int** gArray)
{
    this->GrayArray = gArray;
}

bool** GetBinaryArray( int level )
{
    BArray = new bool * [xsize];
    for (int i = 0; i < xsize; i++ )
    {
        BArray[i] = new bool[ysize];
    }

    binary = new int * [xsize];
    for (int i = 0; i < xsize; i++ )
    {
        binary[i] = new int[ysize];
    }
    fp=fopen("C:\\binary.txt","w");

    int grayC;

    for ( int xVal = 0; xVal < xsize; xVal++ )
    {
        for( int yVal = 0; yVal < ysize; yVal++ )
        {
            grayC = GrayArray[xVal][yVal];

            if ( grayC >= level )
            {
                BArray[xVal][yVal] = true;
                binary[xVal][yVal] = 1;
                fprintf(fp,"%d",binary[xVal][yVal]);
            }
            else
            {
                BArray[xVal][yVal] = false;
                binary[xVal][yVal] = 0;
                fprintf(fp,"%d",binary[xVal][yVal]);
            }

        }// inner for*/
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return BArray;
}
};
```

When I press Retry, then breakpoint showing this line.

```
fprintf(fp,"%d",binary[xVal][yVal]);
```

If I remove these lines then showing breakpoint in main program.

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    // Enabling Windows XP visual effects before any controls are created
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

    // Create the main window and run it
    Application::Run(gcnew Form1());
    return 0;
}
```

Breakpoint showing in `return 0` this line.

Comment: Have the file been opened successfully? You really need to check for errors from functions that can fail.

Comment: Sir,my program is running without any error. But out.doc file is not creating.

Comment: If the program is running without errors, then what is the crash you're having? Are you asking about the crash (which can be because the file doesn't open), or that the file isn't created (which can be because of the same reason)? Check what `fopen` return!

Comment: Sir,actually when I want to create the doc file then it is crashing. But when I delete these lines,which are creating file or printing in doc then also crashing and breakpoint going to main program. But main program has no such line for breaking. I had showed main also in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is a well known problem. I have already solved this topics. In my code I had created text files, docx files and images in C drives. But there was no permission for accessing C drive in my computer. 
Then I had solved by following this steps:

1. If you can access cmd, you can reset the security settings in
       Vista/Windows 7 with the following command: "secedit /configure /cfg
       %windir%\inf\defltbase.inf /db defltbase.sdb /verbose" (no quotes.)
       To see what this command does, go here: How do I restore security
       settings to the default settings?

   NOTE: If you can't access cmd when logged in, use this guide
   System Recovery Options. You can get to the command line when you
   access the System Recovery Options screen.
2. This command seems to give the ownership issue a kick up the
   backside, even though it seems nothing has changed. Go to Explorer,
   right click on C: and go to Properties.
3. Go to the Security tab and then Advanced.
4. Go to the Owner tab. Now you should be able to click Edit.
5. If you don't have Administrators in the list under where it says
   "Change owner to:" then go to "Other users or groups". If you do, go
   straight to step 7.
6. On Others users or groups type in "Administrators" (no quotes) in
   the bottom box. Click Check Name and then OK.
7. Click Administrators and then OK. You've now given yourself
   ownership of C:! (As long as your account is an Administrator, that
   is.)
8. Click OK on the "Advanced Security Settings..." window to get back
   to the Properties window. You should now have a list of the
   Permissions and so on where before you only had something about how
   you couldn't view permissions. Progress, eh?
9. You may need to add in the Adminstrators group to edit their
   permissions. To do this, click "Edit" and then "Add" and type
   "Administrators" (no quotes) in the bottom box. Then hit Check Name
   and then OK.
10. Click Administrators in the list and tick the box in the Allow
    column next to "Full control".
11. Click Apply, you'll likely get a bunch of error messages about how
    this can't be applied to some files and folders. Just OK through
    them all. Once done, you should have access to your C: drive once
    more!

[Source Link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/940ababd-4476-4d21-aec8-a043252e820b/c-is-not-accessible-access-is-denied)